# Salesforce Refresh Token OAuth

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to refresh the access token using the refresh token:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=3MVG9pHRjzOBdkd.WU9DLyfznP.sjOJRXXX_00nLDYSpM_0K7zAOsLrRKf6IWmCv6MxeTorXL7Zzaaea8IXXX&client_secret=3231123171523457&refresh_token=5Aep861VUUSqKxtr91VaZ7Zh54RmFqHE6zD4htOq6vY9edPgkgm9ZeFPwHIzQQvR__XypcEvWnXXX==&format=json"
```

But I keep getting the error `"error_description":"expired access/refresh token"`

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Gotta ask... has the token expired?

Comment: both access token and refresh token not expired.

Comment: We've been seeing something similar with an application that we're working on, but haven't looked into it in depth yet. Few of us use the same login credentials etc. so wonder if we impact each other.

Comment: I wonder if the access token has to be expired before calling refresh token?

Comment: did you find solution on this? I am facing same issue

Comment: You will also get the exact same failure if your `refresh_token` is completely invalid. I was mistakenly trying this with an encrypted token, and it failed with the exact same message. So make sure you *really do* have a valid `refresh_token` first!

Answer (score 15):

I know this is old, but for people that may stumble on this.
I believe this issue is that you can only have **5 access grants per applications**. After this **it starts revoking** refresh tokens **from the oldest** one. More info here:

- [Manage OAuth Access for Your Connected Apps](https://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?loc=help&target=remoteaccess_request_manage.htm&section=integrate)
- [invalid_grant —expired access/refresh token | Issue #80](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/issues/80)

Comment: Great answer. Please note that in my Developer account I found out that the limit is actually 4 tokens per app.

Comment: This is very useful! you saved me hours of debugging!

Answer (score 3):

You have the correct syntax for using a refresh token.  Make sure all of your parameters are URL encoded, since in your example your refresh token has = instead of %3D.

You can also delete the user's refresh token by going to that user's User Detail page inside of setup and revoking the "Remote Access" near the bottom.  Then obtain a new refresh token by going through the oauth flow again and try it in the curl command.

Comment: It is = and not %3D. I made sure.